# Is (a|b)* the same as a*|b*?

Tags: regex, regex-alternation

Is `(a|b)*` the same as `a*|b*`?  In other words, does `(a|b)*` accept string which are combinations of `a`s and `b`s?

Comment: I'm Mr. Meeseeks, look at meee!

Comment: @meeseeks wubalubadubdub!!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is **`(a|b)*`** the same as  **`a*|b*`**?

They are not the same.

- **`a*|b*`** means *"(0 or more `a`s) or (0 or more `b`s)"*
- **`(a|b)*`** means *"0 or more (`a` or `b`)s"*

So, for example, `ab` will be matched by `(a|b)*` but not by `a*|b*`. Note also that anything matched by `a*|b*` will also be matched by `(a|b)*`.

Answer (score 9):

No.

In case of `(a|b)*`, you can mix `A`s and `B`s ([see demo](http://www.regexper.com/#(a%7Cb)%2A)).

In case of `a*|b*`, you can have either `A`s or `B`s ([see demo](http://www.regexper.com/#a%2A%7Cb%2A)).

Answer (score 0):

`a*|b*` denotes {ε, "a", "b", "aa", "bb", "aaa", "bbb", ...}

`(a|b)*` denotes {ε, "a", "b", "aa", "**ab**", "**ba**", "bb", "aaa", **aab**, **abb**, **aba**, **baa** ...}

`ε` denote empty